# Group policy mapped drive connects as Administrator

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy

I've successfully configured a mapped drive via GP but the problem is that it appears to ignore the user's credentials and connect the user as Administrator! Obviously this is a big issue since we use ACLs to control user and group access to folders on that folder and its subfolders. It is configured as:

- Letter S:
- Action Update
- No Reconnect
- No Connect As
- Run in logged-in user's security context (recently applied this one, had the same issue before applying it)

Comment: Try changing the action from Update to Replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shouldn't be happening if you're not using `Connect As`. Chances are you have another script or policy somewhere, or a remembered connection on that computer, that is mapping the drive as the other user.

You can see what policies are applied to the machine by running `gpresult /H` and viewing the resulting page. You should also look in the event logs for System, Application, and Group Policy for hints as to why this policy isn't applying correctly. Without more details, we can only take educated guesses.